# ajax don't run on google cloud hosting

Tags: ajax

I have a google cloud compute engine VM instance, I'm already installed apache2 and PHP, I upload my webpage, my `index.php` is a login page, on my code, when I click my submit button (login) I call with ajax (POST method) mi `login.php` for validating the user and pass, but I never have answer, the ajax never call my `login.php`, it returns a 500 internal server error. I'm adding two images with the error and the code where I have this error.

Do I need to install something more on my VM instance? what I'm doing wrong?

This is the error:

[image]

And this is the code with error:

[image]

Comment: click the links "this is the error" and "this is the code with error" to see the images.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Flavio! Please give the actual code in your question, don't use screenshots of your code.